# How to Get a Sub-String of an XML String Using PHP

Tags: php, xml, xpath

So I have an XML string:

```
http://localhost:8888/?purp=oclcn&xml=<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<record xmlns="http://www.loc.gov/MARC21/slim">
    <leader>00000cam a2200000 a 4500</leader>
    <controlfield tag="001">33333502</controlfield>
    <controlfield tag="008">951010s1996    vtua     b    001 0 eng  </controlfield>
    <datafield ind1=" " ind2=" " tag="010">
      <subfield code="a">   95045582 </subfield>
    </datafield>
    <datafield ind1=" " ind2=" " tag="020">
      <subfield code="a">1858983274</subfield>
    </datafield>
    <datafield ind1=" " ind2=" " tag="020">
      <subfield code="a">9781858983271</subfield>
    </datafield>
    <datafield ind1="0" ind2="0" tag="245">
      <subfield code="a">Economic sociology /</subfield>
      <subfield code="c">edited by Richard Swedberg.</subfield>
    </datafield>
    <datafield ind1=" " ind2=" " tag="260">
      <subfield code="a">Cheltenham, Glos, UK ;</subfield>
      <subfield code="a">Brookfield, Vt., US :</subfield>
      <subfield code="b">E. Elgar Pub. Co.,</subfield>
      <subfield code="c">©1996.</subfield>
    </datafield>
    <datafield ind1=" " ind2=" " tag="300">
      <subfield code="a">xv, 574 pages :</subfield>
      <subfield code="b">illustrations ;</subfield>
      <subfield code="c">25 cm.</subfield>
    </datafield>
    <datafield ind1="1" ind2=" " tag="490">
      <subfield code="a">The international library of critical writings in sociology ;</subfield>
      <subfield code="v">5</subfield>
    </datafield>
    <datafield ind1="1" ind2=" " tag="490">
      <subfield code="a">An Elgar reference collection</subfield>
    </datafield>
    <datafield ind1=" " ind2=" " tag="500">
      <subfield code="a">A collection of journal articles previously published between 1940-1994.</subfield>
    </datafield>
    <datafield ind1=" " ind2="0" tag="650">
      <subfield code="a">Economics</subfield>
      <subfield code="x">Sociological aspects.</subfield>
    </datafield>
    <datafield ind1=" " ind2="0" tag="650">
      <subfield code="a">Sociology.</subfield>
    </datafield>
    <datafield ind1=" " ind2="0" tag="650">
      <subfield code="a">Economics.</subfield>
    </datafield>
    <datafield ind1=" " ind2="6" tag="650">
      <subfield code="a">Économie politique</subfield>
      <subfield code="x">Aspect sociologique.</subfield>
    </datafield>
    <datafield ind1=" " ind2="6" tag="650">
      <subfield code="a">Sociologie.</subfield>
    </datafield>
    <datafield ind1=" " ind2="6" tag="650">
      <subfield code="a">Économie politique.</subfield>
    </datafield>
    <datafield ind1=" " ind2="7" tag="650">
      <subfield code="a">Economics.</subfield>
      <subfield code="2">fast</subfield>
      <subfield code="0">(OCoLC)fst00902116</subfield>
    </datafield>
    <datafield ind1=" " ind2="7" tag="650">
      <subfield code="a">Economics</subfield>
      <subfield code="x">Sociological aspects.</subfield>
      <subfield code="2">fast</subfield>
      <subfield code="0">(OCoLC)fst00902213</subfield>
    </datafield>
    <datafield ind1=" " ind2="7" tag="650">
      <subfield code="a">Sociology.</subfield>
      <subfield code="2">fast</subfield>
      <subfield code="0">(OCoLC)fst01123875</subfield>
    </datafield>
    <datafield ind1="1" ind2="7" tag="650">
      <subfield code="a">Economische sociologie.</subfield>
      <subfield code="2">gtt</subfield>
    </datafield>
    <datafield ind1=" " ind2="7" tag="650">
      <subfield code="a">Sociologie économique.</subfield>
      <subfield code="2">ram</subfield>
    </datafield>
  </record>
```

As you can see, the XML has embedded elements/tags etc.

I'd like to retrieve the last  tag using Xpath and PHP, but still return it as a string (and not an array or object) (and also including the child/sub-tags). How do I go about this?

Answer (score 0):

See http://php.net/manual/de/domdocument.savexml.php, you can call the method `$doc->saveXML($node)` to serialize a DOM node to a string. So select the DOM element (or node in general) and then call that method on the document passing in the selected node to get the XML string representation of the node:

```
$xml = <<<EOD
<record xmlns="http://www.loc.gov/MARC21/slim">
    <leader>00000cam a2200000 a 4500</leader>
    <controlfield tag="001">33333502</controlfield>
    <controlfield tag="008">951010s1996    vtua     b    001 0 eng  </controlfield>
    <datafield ind1=" " ind2=" " tag="010">
      <subfield code="a">   95045582 </subfield>
    </datafield>
    <datafield ind1=" " ind2=" " tag="020">
      <subfield code="a">1858983274</subfield>
    </datafield>
    <datafield ind1=" " ind2=" " tag="020">
      <subfield code="a">9781858983271</subfield>
    </datafield>
    <datafield ind1="0" ind2="0" tag="245">
      <subfield code="a">Economic sociology /</subfield>
      <subfield code="c">edited by Richard Swedberg.</subfield>
    </datafield>
    <datafield ind1=" " ind2=" " tag="260">
      <subfield code="a">Cheltenham, Glos, UK ;</subfield>
      <subfield code="a">Brookfield, Vt., US :</subfield>
      <subfield code="b">E. Elgar Pub. Co.,</subfield>
      <subfield code="c">©1996.</subfield>
    </datafield>
    <datafield ind1=" " ind2=" " tag="300">
      <subfield code="a">xv, 574 pages :</subfield>
      <subfield code="b">illustrations ;</subfield>
      <subfield code="c">25 cm.</subfield>
    </datafield>
    <datafield ind1="1" ind2=" " tag="490">
      <subfield code="a">The international library of critical writings in sociology ;</subfield>
      <subfield code="v">5</subfield>
    </datafield>
    <datafield ind1="1" ind2=" " tag="490">
      <subfield code="a">An Elgar reference collection</subfield>
    </datafield>
    <datafield ind1=" " ind2=" " tag="500">
      <subfield code="a">A collection of journal articles previously published between 1940-1994.</subfield>
    </datafield>
    <datafield ind1=" " ind2="0" tag="650">
      <subfield code="a">Economics</subfield>
      <subfield code="x">Sociological aspects.</subfield>
    </datafield>
    <datafield ind1=" " ind2="0" tag="650">
      <subfield code="a">Sociology.</subfield>
    </datafield>
    <datafield ind1=" " ind2="0" tag="650">
      <subfield code="a">Economics.</subfield>
    </datafield>
    <datafield ind1=" " ind2="6" tag="650">
      <subfield code="a">Économie politique</subfield>
      <subfield code="x">Aspect sociologique.</subfield>
    </datafield>
    <datafield ind1=" " ind2="6" tag="650">
      <subfield code="a">Sociologie.</subfield>
    </datafield>
    <datafield ind1=" " ind2="6" tag="650">
      <subfield code="a">Économie politique.</subfield>
    </datafield>
    <datafield ind1=" " ind2="7" tag="650">
      <subfield code="a">Economics.</subfield>
      <subfield code="2">fast</subfield>
      <subfield code="0">(OCoLC)fst00902116</subfield>
    </datafield>
    <datafield ind1=" " ind2="7" tag="650">
      <subfield code="a">Economics</subfield>
      <subfield code="x">Sociological aspects.</subfield>
      <subfield code="2">fast</subfield>
      <subfield code="0">(OCoLC)fst00902213</subfield>
    </datafield>
    <datafield ind1=" " ind2="7" tag="650">
      <subfield code="a">Sociology.</subfield>
      <subfield code="2">fast</subfield>
      <subfield code="0">(OCoLC)fst01123875</subfield>
    </datafield>
    <datafield ind1="1" ind2="7" tag="650">
      <subfield code="a">Economische sociologie.</subfield>
      <subfield code="2">gtt</subfield>
    </datafield>
    <datafield ind1=" " ind2="7" tag="650">
      <subfield code="a">Sociologie économique.</subfield>
      <subfield code="2">ram</subfield>
    </datafield>
  </record>

EOD;

$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadXML($xml);

$elements = $doc->getElementsByTagNameNS('*', 'datafield');
$lastElement = $elements[$elements->length - 1];

echo $doc->saveXML($lastElement);
```

Using XPath would not change anything about serializing the node, here is the same example but using an XPath expression to select the last datafield element:

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadXML($xml);

$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
$xpath->registerNamespace('df', $doc->documentElement->namespaceURI);


$lastElement = $xpath->query('(//df:datafield)[last()]')[0];

echo $doc->saveXML($lastElement);
```

Comment: your solution doesn't make use of XPath. It is different with XPath, because using DOMXPath, returns a DOMNodeList, which in turn returns DOMElement (and not DOMDocument), which doesn't have the saveXML method.

Comment: Well, if you have a DOMElement you also have an owning DOMDocument and you can then call `$doc-saveXML($domElementNode)`, it is not really important whether the node you have was selected using `getElementsByTagName` or using XPath or created otherwise, if you want to serialize it you can do it as explained in the first paragraph of my answer. Selecting nodes with XPath does not change that approach at all.

Comment: If you did not have the document in the current context, you can use the `DOMNode::$ownerDocument` property `$node->ownerDocument->saveXml($node);`

Answer (score 0):

Presumably what you're looking for is

```
if (($xml = simplexml_load_string($xml_string)) !== FALSE) {
    $xml->registerXPathNamespace('marc', 'http://www.loc.gov/MARC21/slim');

    // Retrieve the last "datafield" element
    $results = $xml->xpath('/marc:record/marc:datafield[last()]');
    if ($results !== FALSE and ($datafield = reset($results)) !== FALSE) {
        // Process the element, or simply output it with:
        echo $datafield->saveXML();
    }
}
```